# In which order should classes be declared in C++?

Tags: c++, class

Say I got this C++ code:

```
class class1{
    class2 *x;
}

class class2{
    class1 *x;
}
```

The compiler would give an error in line 2 because it couldn't find class2, and the same if i switched the order of the classes. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Two things - one, you need semicolons after class declarations:

```
class class1{
    class2 *x;
};

class class2{
    class1 *x;
};
```

Two, you can create a declaration in front of the definitions of the classes. That tells the compiler that this class exists, and you have yet to define it. In this case, put a `class2` declaration in front of the definition of `class1`:

```
class class2 ;

class class1{
    class2 *x;
};

class class2{
    class1 *x;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer [Forward declarations](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/)

Answer (score 2):

Declare class2 first:

```
class class2;
class class1{
    class2 *x;
};

class class2{
    class1 *x;
};
```