# Error finding a Class even when it's predefined

Tags: c++, class, object, incomplete-type

```
class Slice ;

class Apple{
  ...
  Slice x;
};

class Slice{
    ...
};
```

Even though I defined that class Slice exists.
When I call it in my class Apple to create a Slice object 'x', the compiler gives me an error:field x has an incomplete type.
If I swap the order of classes, so that Slice gets made first, the error is gone and program compiles with no problems.

Very similar problem to what 
[In which order should classes be declared in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757241/in-which-order-should-classes-be-declared-in-c)
had. But for some reason predefining classes doesnt work for me.

Picture of my problem if you need specific
http://gyazo.com/cf6fdf2894c34afba4ef0e352510fcfd
Its just some gibberish code I made for learning how to change state of an object when its inside another object.

Comment: Where did you read that a forward declaration is sufficient when instantiating a type?

Comment: Just as a note on the title.  "Declaring" and "Defining" are different things.  The Slice class is not predefined, it is predeclared.  The difference is that the compiler knows how big a defined class is, how it's layed out, etc.  But from the declaration, the compiler only knows the Slice is a class.  Nothing else.

Comment: -caveman, ohhh, I see it now. I messed up the tittle I guess, sorry about that. English is not my native.

@LightnessRacesinOrbit Didnt really read it anywhere. Was just messing around with classes/objects figuring out how they work as I just got my first c++ classes in college. Couldnt find/google a solution for my problem (besides the one I linked which didnt work on my example), so I asked here. Hope I'm not troubling you people.

Comment: Well it's better to make choices and decisions based upon facts that you have read e.g. in a C++ book, rather than just guessing then acting surprised when it doesn't work :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class Slice;`

Forward declarations work if you are subsequentally declaring pointers or references to the incomplete type, and not when you're using an instance of the type.

Your `Apple` class is using a full instance of `Slice`, so the compiler needs to know what `Slice` actually is so as to properly layout the `Apple` class.  Since `Slice` is an incomplete type, the compiler gives you the error.

To address your issue, you can declare a pointer or reference to `Slice` in your `Apple` class.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense.
Guess ill have to read up on how to reference to another class when I need to use it and its methods before the class is created. (So I dont have to sort them in specific order).

Thanks Paul, you saved me going bald from googling while scratching my head. Now I have something specific to look up.

Comment: @Wiking: _"(So I dont have to sort them in specific order)"_ It's likely that you can't avoid this, but that's okay.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well... that sounds ominous, heh.
So, another silly question (would be rude from me to make another topic for something that's probably simple for you to answer): First problem is solved by referencing class Slice with `Slice *x`. But what do I do when I need to reference a function from a class that's not made yet? Such as for example `int getAppleSlice (return x.getSlice(););` where `getSlice()` is actually from that Slice class that has not been made yet.
I get an error and asked if I meant to use ->.

Comment: @Wiking: If you've changed your member `x` from a `Slice` to a `Slice*`, then there are a few things you need to do. It's not just changing `.` to `->`, but also deciding upon and implementing the ownership and lifetime rules for your pointed-to object. Honestly I'd just keep your code as it was originally but re-order the class definitions: introducing dynamic allocation for this is going to make a mess.