# How to forward declare a class that inherits from another class c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

I've created a class that has a bunch of inherited classes (parent classes) so that I can use polymorphism but the problem is that there are two classes that are calling each other.

So I need to forward declare them and I can forward declare one class but when I forward declare the inherited class the compiler says it can't change pointer from one to the other.

Is there a way to make the forward declaration of the inherited class so that it states it inherits from it?
Ex:

```
class Shape;
class Circle:Shape;
```

Comment: I suppose you already have read [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns/Creational_Patterns)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902751/how-to-clone-object-in-c-or-is-there-another-solution

Comment: @RSahu ... how is that related?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In which order should classes be declared in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757241/in-which-order-should-classes-be-declared-in-c)

Comment: @Christophe so that shows how to forward declare a class.  But how does that help with pointer conversion with only the forward declaration, which is the OP's problem?

Comment: @Christophe, it was when the original question asked about creating prototypes - 'How to make a prototype of a class that inherits from another class c++?"

Comment: If you are going to be using `Circle` as an incomplete type after the forward declaration, why do you need the information that it inherits from `Shape` as well?

Comment: Sorry, I lack imagination, but I don't understand the problem of the OP.  It would be usefull to show us a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the family tree, after the class name, when making forward declarations.

```
class Shape;
class Circle;
class Rectangle;
```

When you declare classes that use inheritance, the compiler would appreciate the full declaration of the parent classes.

A rule of thumb is that the types for declaration of pointers and references can be resolved using forward declarations.  Any code that accesses elements of a class via pointers or references needs the complete class declaration.

Comment: In particular, casting from a derived cast to a base class counts as using the class, not just referencing or pointing to the class so you need the full declaration available.